# Parts of Menu not displaying IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm not very technical so apologies if this is really obvious. I have researched online and can't find the answer. The site is on concept url: http://sgstemp.dreamhosters.com/ it displays fine in FF, Chrome & Safari but in IE part of the navigation menu disappears on the pages with a slider. Any idea how I can fix this. Also the slider doesn’t work at all in IE8...

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code please?

Answer (score 1):

Versions of internet explorer lower than 10 (I think) can't see the header and footer tags, try changing them to plain divs.

As for the animations in IE8, I'm pretty sure none of the fancy CSS3 ,jQuery or data-prefixes wil be compatible - try turning it into a flash animation?

Comment: Rather than changing those elements to divs, consider wrapping them in fallback elements with the child element name as an ID value. This allows HTML5 layouts but with legacy browser support.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget to specify the z-index property for your Contacts, and News menu items.
specify the z-index to bubble them up on the top of the view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you're using HTML5 elements like `<section>` and `<header>`.

These are new element names and are not recognised by IE8 or earlier. You will get bizarre styling bugs if you use them.

Fortunately there is a solution to this: There is a script called [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/). Adding this script to your page will fix this issue in old IE versions, and it will then recognise these new tags as being valid.

There's also another script you might want to try called [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which includes the same functionality as html5shiv, but also provides features for helping you detect missing browser features.

So add one or other of those scripts to your page, and it should solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could just switch to using `<div>` elements for everything, with classes to define their semantics instead of the new HTML5 tags.

Comment: The html5shiv was already implemented however tried again and still no impact on the display of the navigation menu.

Comment: I tried turning off compatibility mode in IE and the menu works perfectly but it destroyed the rest of the page.